# Show validation errors in crud api

Tags: api, validation, debugging, cakephp-3.0, crud

How can I display the validations error and messages in the returned response.
I just retrieve response like this:

```
{
  "message": "4 validation errors occurred",
  "url": "/api/posts",
  "code": 422
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it [here](https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/listeners/api.html#exception-handler):

The Exception handler need a configuration:

-If your CakePHP >= 3.3 (middleware feature):

```
'Error' => [
    'errorLevel' => E_ALL,
    'exceptionRenderer' => 'Crud\Error\JsonApiExceptionRenderer',
    'skipLog' => [],
    'log' => true,
    'trace' => true,
],
```

-If your CakePHP < 3.3 :

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {

  public function initialize()
  {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Crud->config(['listeners.api.exceptionRenderer' => 'App\Error\ExceptionRenderer']);
  }
}
```